# IPHONE - How to initialize a button using editButtonItem

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I want to use table edit function. I know 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
However I want to set a UIButton set it as editButtonItem or can do edit table function

Answer (score 0):

just write your code in onclick of UIButton ,that s

-(IBAction)deletebuttonPresed:(id)sender
{

table.editing=YES;

}

Answer (score 0):

You cant use self.editButtonItem because it is present when your class is subclass of UITableView.

But you can achieve same functionality by the following code-

use a bool variable (declare in .h file says isEdit).

```
-(IBAction)editTable
{
  if(!isEdit)
  {
    isEdit=YES;
    yourTableView.editing=YES;
  }
  else
   {
     isEdit=NO;
     yourTableView.editing=NO;
   }
}
```

bind this IBAction to the button. you can also change the text of the button and style also by setting property of the button.